# How to return DB Data in nested json format?

Tags: java, json, list, spring-mvc, treeview

Already i return my data in json format but i want to convert it into nested json format data.

my code is written in spring such that is following

```
@GET
@Path("/findall")
public List<UserRole> getAll() {

             return userroleservice.findAll();
}
```

This program return the following output

```
[{"roleId":1,"roleName":"system Admin","createUser":"1","createActive":"N"},{"roleId":2,"roleName":"admin","createUser":"1","createActive":"Y"},{"roleId":3,"roleName":"system Admin","createUser":"1","createActive":"Y"}]
```

How to convert it to nested json format  like

```
  [{ "id": 1, "data": "Category", "attr": { "id": "1", "selected": false }, "children":
                [
                    { "id": 2, "data": "SubCategory1", "attr": { "id": "2",      "selected": false }, "children":
                            [{ "id": 4, "data": "Item1", "attr": { "id": "4", "selected": false }, "children": [] },
                             { "id": 5, "data": "Item2", "attr": { "id": "5", "selected": false }, "children": [] },
                             { "id": 6, "data": "Item3", "attr": { "id": "6", "selected": false }, "children": [] }
                            ]
                    },

                    { "id": 3, "data": "SubCategory2", "attr": { "id": "3", "selected": false }, "children":
                             [{ "id": 7, "data": "Item4", "attr": { "id": "7", "selected": false }, "children": [] },
                              { "id": 8, "data": "Item5", "attr": { "id": "8", "selected": false }, "children": [] },
                              { "id": 9, "data": "Item6", "attr": { "id": "9", "selected": false }, "children": [] }
                             ]
                    }
                ]
}];
```

or How to return DB data in nested json format ??

Please anybody help.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new class that corresponds to the JSON format you want to have. Generate the desired java classes using [JSON TO POJO](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/) link
2. After you are done with the POJO generation write a translator that will translate the DB object to your  new POJO object.
3. Pass the same to next layer

Comment: Please some coding for example...And can i append to Gson object?? like